Storybook: add different script tags to head based on story tags
We have a storybook setup for the UI components we built – this is working great.
Now, we also want to have stories that are displaying more than a single component and some of them need to add HTML-tags to the header of the preview iframe. I know about the previewHead() function in the storybook-config, but I could only use this globally and not on a per-story-basis ...
Ideally, I could add a tag to certain stories and then if the tag is present, add styles/scripts to the head. But as far as I can see, this is not possible... did I miss anything?
